# Time Duration for staff on a night shift with onguard system accesscontrol database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the Lenel Onguard with SQL server dBase to make the time attendance system for our employees.
I summarize each day's transaction to make their first entry and last exit for each day and get the datediff. to get the time duration. But the problem is with night shift employees, it is showing the time out which happened in the morning of the same day where actual exit is on the next day. so the datediff. returning with wrong value. Any solutions are most welcomed!

This code gives me the wrong value for night shift.can anyone help me out to modify the code to fit staff on day shift and those on night shift  in which their exit time is on next day

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    BADGE.ID, 
    UPPER(ISNULL(dbo.EMP.FIRSTNAME, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.EMP.LASTNAME, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.EMP.MIDNAME, ' '))AS NAMES, 
    A.*,
    B.TIMEOUT, 
    datediff(hour,a.[TIMEIN],b.TIMEOUT) HoursWorked 
FROM (
    SELECT empid,convert(date,event_time_utc)[Date],ltrim(right(convert(varchar(25), DATEADD(HOUR,3,CAST(min(event_time_utc)AS TIME)), 100), 7)) TIMEIN 
    FROM events INNER JOIN READER ON EVENTS.DEVID=READER.READERID INNER JOIN EVENT ON EVENTS.EVENTTYPE=EVENT.EVTYPEID AND EVENTS.EVENTID=EVENT.EVID
    WHERE  READERID=19 AND PANELID=16 AND EVDESCR='Access Granted' 
    GROUP BY empid,convert(date,event_time_utc)
) A 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT empid,convert(date,event_time_utc)[Date],ltrim(right(convert(varchar(25), DATEADD(HOUR,3,CAST(MAX(event_time_utc)AS TIME)), 100), 7)) TIMEOUT
    FROM events INNER JOIN READER ON EVENTS.DEVID=READER.READERID INNER JOIN EVENT ON EVENTS.EVENTTYPE=EVENT.EVTYPEID AND EVENTS.EVENTID=EVENT.EVID
    WHERE READERID=20 AND PANELID=16 AND EVDESCR='Access Granted' 
    GROUP BY empid,convert(date,event_time_utc)
) B on A.empid=b.empid and a.[Date]=b.[Date]
JOIN Emp on emp.id=A.EmpID 
JOIN BADGE ON BADGE.EMPID=A.EMPID
ORDER BY DATE
```

Results

```
EmpID  TIMEIN                    Timeout
1       2014-08-21 21:38:06.000    2014-08-22 06:00:10.000                  
2       2014-08-22 22:30:00.000    2014-08-23 06:00:10.000
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! One important piece of posting code is making it as readable as possible.  I formatted your code a little to get it to a place where others will be able to read it more easily and thus be more willing to answer your question.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: hi @amira Beddiafi  my expected output is like below                       empid           Timein                                  Timeout
1       2014-08-21 21:38:06.000    2014-08-22 06:00:10.000                  
2       2014-08-22 22:30:00.000    2014-08-23 06:00:10.000

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the first three paragraphs of the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: You must not group by date, as the night shift employees will have there TimeIn and Timeout on different days, please check my solution below, plus if you provide more information a more accurate solution can be found.

Answer (score 0):

In summary you have Event/s table, that have EmpId, the datetime of each scan, and there is no info about TimeOut or TimeIn, and you want to find that, well from the information you provided its a bit hard, Im sure you have more data that will help make this simpler, like the shift hours, any limitations, is over hours accepted and more boundary information.

Lets say you dont, so we will need to put some assumptions, for example, as the employees work in shifts, I will assume that the shift is 8-10 hours, and if I see a gab in scanning more than 14 hours that the employee went home, I will not care if he is a night shift employee or a day shift, if there is a gab between two sequentialscans more than 14 hours that mean he went home, or in other words that is a TimeOut, and then next entry is a TimeIn.

You did not provide any table structure or data, so I will ignore your query and focus on the problem you want to solve, so I will assume I have only one Events Table that have all the data, you can adapt this to your query if this helps you.

I will create a memory table here and fill it with EmpId 1, that is a on the day shift and EmpId 2 that is on the night shift, I will assume some data and do some calculations.

```
Declare @Events TABLE(
EmpId int,
event_time_utc datetime
)

insert into @Events values
(1, '2014-08-21 07:38:06.000'),--first day for emp1
(1, '2014-08-21 08:39:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-21 14:44:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-21 15:38:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-21 16:01:06.000'),

(1, '2014-08-22 07:40:06.000'),--second day for emp1
(1, '2014-08-22 08:50:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-22 14:30:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-22 15:30:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-22 16:05:06.000'),

(1, '2014-08-23 07:38:06.000'),--3rd day for emp1
(1, '2014-08-23 08:39:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-23 14:44:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-23 15:38:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-23 16:01:06.000'),

(1, '2014-08-24 07:40:06.000'),--4th day for emp1
(1, '2014-08-24 08:50:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-24 14:30:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-24 15:30:06.000'),
(1, '2014-08-24 16:05:06.000'),

(2, '2014-08-21 21:38:06.000'),--first day for emp2 -- night shift
(2, '2014-08-21 23:38:06.000'),
(2, '2014-08-22 01:38:06.000'),
(2, '2014-08-22 04:05:06.000'),

(2, '2014-08-22 21:38:06.000'),--first day for emp2 -- night shift
(2, '2014-08-22 23:38:06.000'),
(2, '2014-08-23 01:38:06.000'),
(2, '2014-08-23 04:05:06.000'),

(2, '2014-08-23 21:38:06.000'),--3rd day for emp2 -- night shift
(2, '2014-08-23 23:38:06.000'),
(2, '2014-08-24 01:38:06.000'),
(2, '2014-08-24 04:05:06.000'),

(2, '2014-08-24 21:38:06.000'),--4th day for emp2 -- night shift
(2, '2014-08-24 23:38:06.000'),
(2, '2014-08-25 01:38:06.000'),
(2, '2014-08-25 04:05:06.000')
```

Now I will use the below CTEs to figure out the TimeIn and TimeOut and calculate the hours.

```
;with cte as (
--get the next entry, and set a row number based on EmpID and time
select *
    ,LEAD(event_time_utc,1) over (partition by EmpId order by event_time_utc) nextEntry 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by EmpId order by event_time_utc) seq
    from @Events
),cte2 as (
    --count the hours between this entry and the one after
    select *,datediff(hour,event_time_utc,nextEntry) [hours] from cte
),cte3 as (
    --if gab more then 14 or if its null, set it as time in 
    select *
        ,case when seq=1 then event_time_utc 
              when [hours]>14 then nextEntry
        else null end [TimeIn]
        from cte2
),cte4 as (
--find the seq for the Timeout 
    select *,
    Isnull(
        lead(seq) over (partition by EmpId order by event_time_utc)
        ,(select top(1) cte.seq from cte  where cte.EmpId=cte3.EmpId order by event_time_utc desc))  [TimeOutSeq]
    from cte3 where TimeIn is not null
    ),cte5 as (
    --convert the seq to timeout by joining to the same table using the TimeOutSeq to help
        select cte4.*,cte3.event_time_utc [TimeOut] from cte4
        left outer join cte3 on cte3.seq=cte4.TimeOutSeq and cte3.EmpId=cte4.EmpId
    )
    --select * from cte3
    --finally show the needed fileds only, and the hours for each employee
    select EmpId,seq,TimeIn,[TimeOut],datediff(Hour,TimeIn,[TimeOut]) [hours] from cte5 order by EmpId, TimeIn
```

The result for my set of data is as below:-

```
EmpId   Seq TimeIn                  TimeOut                 hours
1       1   2014-08-21 07:38:06.000 2014-08-21 16:01:06.000 9
1       5   2014-08-22 07:40:06.000 2014-08-22 16:05:06.000 9
1       10  2014-08-23 07:38:06.000 2014-08-23 16:01:06.000 9
1       15  2014-08-24 07:40:06.000 2014-08-24 16:05:06.000 9
2       1   2014-08-21 21:38:06.000 2014-08-22 04:05:06.000 7
2       4   2014-08-22 21:38:06.000 2014-08-23 04:05:06.000 7
2       8   2014-08-23 21:38:06.000 2014-08-24 04:05:06.000 7
2       12  2014-08-24 21:38:06.000 2014-08-25 04:05:06.000 7
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your  response iam sorry i forget to provide what shows its and exit time and what shows its an entry time. in events table we have devid thats a readerid on reader table and foreign key on events table for example                           Readerid 19 is an entry reader and if staff goes through it thats an entrance time  Readerid 20  is an exit reader and if staff goes through it thats an exit time         So somebody can goes through these readers several times but i only intend to pick the first entrance and the last exit ,

Comment: SERIALNUM DEVID  EVENTID MACHINE EVENT_TIME_UTC
1513850367 19 77                  1          12/21/17 10:01
1513850372 19 8                  1          12/21/17 10:01
1513850374 19 199                      1        12/21/17 10:01
1513850375 19 2                      1        12/21/17 10:01
1513850376 19 2                      1        12/21/17 10:01
1513850377 19 54 1 12/21/17 10:01
1513850381 19 10 1 12/21/17 10:03
1513850394 20 8 1 12/21/17 10:18
1513850396 20 199 1 12/21/17 10:18

Comment: please update the original question, and add all your data there. as in the comment its not clear. and try to use the idea i presented to solve your problem.

Comment: below here is structure of events table

SERIALNUM DEVID EVENTID EMPID EVENT_TIME_UTC
1513850367 19 77 1 08/21/14 21:38:06.000
1513850372 20 8 1 08/22/14 06:00:10.000
1513850374 19 199 1 08/22/14 10:01:15.000
1513850375 20 2 1 08/22/14 10:11:19.000
1513850376 19 2 2 08/21/14 22:01:26.000
1513850377 20 54 2 08/22/14 07:01:09.000
1513850381 19 10 2 12/22/14 10:03:12.000
1513850394 20 8 2 12/21/14 10:18:17.000
1513850396 19 199 2 12/21/14 11:18:23:000

Comment: HI @ALI here is a link for full question                                                           https://stackoverflow.com/q/57671782/11803409

Comment: Hi @koech, you must not add a new duplicate question, update your original post please. the notes part here is your feed back of trying the solution provided, not to add more details to the question.

Comment: noted @ali back to the question ,from your code sir it assumes that the first event is timein and after 14 hours next event is timeout but thats not the case with my scenario since we have devid in events table which describes whats timein and timeout for example devid 19 is timein and devid 20 timeout

Comment: Sorry you got it wrong, I did not say after 14 hours the next event is timeout. My idea if you see a gab between the signs for more than 14 hours, then that mean its an indicator of a new day. to make it more clear, please provide some sample data and the structure for your tables so more people can help you, and please update your question to have all the facts too.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir , with this link stackoverflow.com/q/57671782/11803409 i provided more information with sample data in db and also shows the structure of db kindly have a look at it as you will got more information and more logic to help me solve this.I realized with this post i had not provided the structure of database with sample data