# time duration for staff on night shift with lenel onguard

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the Lenel Onguard with SQL server dBase to make the time attendance system for our employees. I summarize each day's transaction to make their first entry and last exit for each day and get the datediff. to get the time duration. But the problem is with night shift employees, it is showing the time out which happened in the morning of the same day where actual exit is on the next day. so the datediff. returning with wrong value. Any solutions are most welcomed!

This code below gives me the wrong  exit time for staff on the night shift but correct entrance time and also the code works well on staff on DAY shift. as per my code i have several tables but the most important table here is events table :                                                               events table has a column known as devid which is a foreign key here and primary key on readers table. Staff goes through reader 19 or devid 19 in events table as foreign key for entrance

i tried the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    BADGE.ID, 
    UPPER(ISNULL(dbo.EMP.FIRSTNAME, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.EMP.LASTNAME, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.EMP.MIDNAME, ' '))AS NAMES, 
    A.*,
    B.TIMEOUT, 
    datediff(hour,a.[TIMEIN],b.TIMEOUT) HoursWorked 
FROM (
    SELECT empid,convert(date,event_time_utc)[Date],ltrim(right(convert(varchar(25), DATEADD(HOUR,3,CAST(min(event_time_utc)AS TIME)), 100), 7)) TIMEIN 
    FROM events INNER JOIN READER ON EVENTS.DEVID=READER.READERID INNER JOIN EVENT ON EVENTS.EVENTTYPE=EVENT.EVTYPEID AND EVENTS.EVENTID=EVENT.EVID
    WHERE  READERID=19 AND PANELID=16 AND EVDESCR='Access Granted' 
    GROUP BY empid,convert(date,event_time_utc)
) A 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT empid,convert(date,event_time_utc)[Date],ltrim(right(convert(varchar(25), DATEADD(HOUR,3,CAST(MAX(event_time_utc)AS TIME)), 100), 7)) TIMEOUT
    FROM events INNER JOIN READER ON EVENTS.DEVID=READER.READERID INNER JOIN EVENT ON EVENTS.EVENTTYPE=EVENT.EVTYPEID AND EVENTS.EVENTID=EVENT.EVID
    WHERE READERID=20 AND PANELID=16 AND EVDESCR='Access Granted' 
    GROUP BY empid,convert(date,event_time_utc)
) B on A.empid=b.empid and a.[Date]=b.[Date]
JOIN Emp on emp.id=A.EmpID 
JOIN BADGE ON BADGE.EMPID=A.EMPID
ORDER BY DATE
```

This my expected result

```
EmpID        TIMEIN                    Timeout
1       2014-08-21 21:38:06.000    2014-08-22 06:00:10.000                  
2       2014-08-22 22:30:00.000    2014-08-23 06:00:10.000
```

below here is structure of events table

```
SERIALNUM DEVID EVENTID EMPID   EVENT_TIME_UTC
1513850367  19  77      1           08/21/14 21:38:06.000
1513850372  20  8       1           08/22/14 06:00:10.000
1513850374  19  199     1           08/22/14 10:01:15.000
1513850375  20  2       1           08/22/14 10:11:19.000
1513850376  19  2       2           08/21/14 22:01:26.000
1513850377  20  54      2           08/22/14 07:01:09.000
1513850381  19  10      2           08/22/14 10:03:12.000
1513850394  20  8       2           08/22/14 10:18:17.000
1513850396  19  199     2           08/22/14 11:18:23:000
```

Comment: What is your last time of exit for a day? Other way, from which time you starts counting IN time for a day?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want `lead()` or `min()` as a window function:

```
select empid, event_time_utc as timein, timeout
from (select e.*,
             min(case when e.devid <> 19 then e.event_time end) over
                 (partition by e.empid order by event_time_utc desc) as timeout
      from events e
     ) e
where devid = 19;
```

Comment: thanks for your response but in this situation staff can come in and goes out several times so  what i need is first in and last out  for each day

Comment: @koechnathan . . .  You should be able to figure out how to aggregate this result into what you need.